# Table 1 is not associated with table 2

Tags: mysql, orm, inner-join, cakephp-3.0

I have two Table Class:

```
            <?php
            namespace App\Model\Table;
            use Cake\ORM\Table;
            use App\Model\Entity\Comlib;
            use Cake\ORM\Query;
            use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
            use Cake\ORM\Validator;
            use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

            class ComlibsTable extends Table {

            public function initialize(array $config) {
                parent::initialize($config);
             $this->table('questions');
            // JOIN THE TABLES TOMORROW 
            $this->hasMany('Answers' , [
            'foreignKey' => 'question_id'
            ]);



                }

            public function LFM( $live_req) {

            $answers = TableRegistry::get('questions');

            $query = $answers->find()
                    ->distinct(['question.id'])
                    ->matching('Answers', function ($q) use ($options) {
                        return $q->where(['Answers.id IN'=> '1']);
                    });
                    $query = $query->all();
            //want Answers five of then
            return $query;

                }
            }
            ?>
```

the 2nd Table :

```
            use Cake\ORM\Table;
            use Cake\ORM\Query;
            use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

            class AnswersTable extends Table {

                public function initialize(array $config) {
                    parent::initialize($config);
                    $this->table('answers');


                }

            }
```

In the database I have a question table and answer table, answer table has a foreign key named : question_id.
What I want to do is I want to select everything from question and join it with answers via id , possible innerjoin
and the error I get is:

> questions is not associated with answers

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why do you call you questionsTable ComlibsTable?  and whyn you create a variable named $answers and initialize it to TableRegistry::get('questions')

Comment: for some purpose i called it comlibs , but i then used $this->table('question'); to tell the program what table to use , you saying variable , i decided to use answer to instantiate the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing the table in your database with cakePHP `Table` class

when you call `TableRegistry::get()` you have to pass the name of the Table class. So the right syntax would be

```
$answers = TableRegistry::get('Comlibs');
```

and cake will instantiate a new object of `ComlibsTable` Class

Anyway you don't even need to do this because you're already inside the ComlibsTable and you can use `$this` to reference the Table. So all you have to do is

```
$query = $this->find()
    ->distinct(['question.id'])
    ->matching('Answers', function ($q) use ($options) {
        return $q->where(['Answers.id IN'=> '1']);
     })
    ->all();
```

Comment: tnx , after 1 day of search, and you solve it with a $this , silly me